# Combine two pyspark dataframes (having different rows ) such that other dataframe gets added as new columns.(Null values in columns for extra rows)

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, join, pyspark

I have a usecase where i need to combine two pyspark dataframes such that the other dataframe gets added to original one as new columns. Important is to understand that they can have different rows.

For example if i have below data 3 versions:

df1 schema:  `Name|ID|past_features_height|past_features_width|past_features_version`

Data:

```
    A|123|34|42|version1
    A|123|30|45|version2
    A|123|33|47|version3
```

df2 schema:  `Name|ID|future_features_height|future_features_width|future_features_version`

Data:

```
    A|123|32|45|version1
    A|123|35|42|version2
    A|123|37|43|version3
    A|123|39|46|version4
    A|123|40|32|version5
```

Result dataframe schema:
`Name|ID|past_features_height|past_features_width|past_features_version|future_features_width|future_features_version`

```
    A|123|34|42|version1|32|45|version1
    A|123|30|45|version2|35|42|version2
    A|123|33|47|version3|37|43|version3
    A|123|Null|Null|Null|39|46|version4
    A|123|Null|Null|Null|40|32|version5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In case you can join by version directly then you can use:**

```py
data_old = [("A", 123, 34, 42, "version1"),
        ("A", 123, 30, 45, "version2"),
        ("A", 123, 33, 47, "version3")]

df_old = spark.createDataFrame(data_old, ["Name", "ID", "past_features_height", "past_features_width", "features_version"])\

data_new = [("A", 123, 32, 45, "version1"),
            ("A", 123, 35, 42, "version2"),
            ("A", 123, 37, 43, "version3"),
            ("A", 123, 39, 46, "version4"),
            ("A", 123, 40, 32, "version5")]
df_new = spark.createDataFrame(data_new, ["Name", "ID", "future_features_height", "future_features_width", "features_version"])\

df_old.join(df_new, ["Name", "ID", "features_version"], "full_outer").show()
```

```
+----+---+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+----------------------+---------------------+
|Name| ID|features_version|past_features_height|past_features_width|future_features_height|future_features_width|
+----+---+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+----------------------+---------------------+
|   A|123|        version1|                  34|                 42|                    32|                   45|
|   A|123|        version2|                  30|                 45|                    35|                   42|
|   A|123|        version3|                  33|                 47|                    37|                   43|
|   A|123|        version4|                null|               null|                    39|                   46|
|   A|123|        version5|                null|               null|                    40|                   32|
+----+---+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

**But if you can't, then you need to add another identifier to order the versions between the two df, so in this case you can use the `row_number` over a `Window` function like this:**

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

data_old = [("A", 123, 34, 42, "version1"),
        ("A", 123, 30, 45, "version2"),
        ("A", 123, 33, 47, "version3")]

partition_old = Window.partitionBy("Name", "ID").orderBy("past_features_version")
df_old = spark.createDataFrame(data_old, ["Name", "ID", "past_features_height", "past_features_width", "past_features_version"])\
            .withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(partition_old))

data_new = [("A", 123, 32, 45, "version1"),
            ("A", 123, 35, 42, "version2"),
            ("A", 123, 37, 43, "version3"),
            ("A", 123, 39, 46, "version4"),
            ("A", 123, 40, 32, "version5")]
partition_new = Window.partitionBy("Name", "ID").orderBy("future_features_version")
df_new = spark.createDataFrame(data_new, ["Name", "ID", "future_features_height", "future_features_width", "future_features_version"])\
            .withColumn("row_number", row_number().over(partition_new))

df_old.join(df_new, ["Name", "ID", "row_number"], "full_outer").show()
```

```
+----+---+----------+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|Name| ID|row_number|past_features_height|past_features_width|past_features_version|future_features_height|future_features_width|future_features_version|
+----+---+----------+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
|   A|123|         1|                  34|                 42|             version1|                    32|                   45|               version1|
|   A|123|         2|                  30|                 45|             version2|                    35|                   42|               version2|
|   A|123|         3|                  33|                 47|             version3|                    37|                   43|               version3|
|   A|123|         4|                null|               null|                 null|                    39|                   46|               version4|
|   A|123|         5|                null|               null|                 null|                    40|                   32|               version5|
+----+---+----------+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------+----------------------+---------------------+-----------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the example , explanation and the help on this.

Comment: Thanks @VivekKaushik, hope you up vote as well if you found it useful!